# XMPP block messages

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I am trying to block communications in my XMPP client (Built on top of strophe.js). The problem is it only blocks my messages to a contact I am trying to "mute" BUT doesn't block any incoming messages from that contact.

Here is the logic (based on http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#privacy):

1) Add "bill@domain.me" to my "block" list

```
var recipient = "bill@domain.me"
var block = $iq({type: 'set'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:privacy'}).
c('list', {name: 'block'}).
c('item', {type: 'jid', value: recipient, action: 'deny', order: 1}).
c('message');
```

2) Make this list active

```
var setListActive = $iq({type: 'set'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:privacy'}).c("active", {name: "block"});           
SGN.connection.sendIQ(setListActive);
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I might be wrong* but what I've understood is it is the way it should work.

If you check the list you were adding jids to you'll see that they are all there:

```
var getMyPrivacyList = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:privacy'}).c("list", {name: "block"});          
APP.connection.sendIQ(getMyPrivacyList,function success(response) { console.log(response) });
```

However if you want to block incoming messages you'd have to **manually check** senders's jids against this list every time message comes in.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send unsubscribe presence to that buddy as well. and have to put an handler to handle presence type="unsubscribed". on that handler, send unsubscribe presence.

**code for blocking friend**

```
const blockFriend_Stanza=function(fromJid, friendJid,cb_success){
    connection.send($pres({ to: friendJid, type: "unavailable", }));
    connection.send($pres({ to: friendJid, type: "unsubscribe" }));


    let UnblockIq=$iq({ 'type': 'set', 'id': 'blockFriend', from: fromJid  })
                .c("block", {xmlns: "urn:xmpp:blocking"}).c("item", {jid: friendJid});
    connection.sendIQ(UnblockIq,
        response=>{ 
            console.log("onClick_lnkBlockFriend",response)
            if(response.getAttribute("type")=="result"){
                cb_success();                
            }
        },
        error=>{ 
            console.log("onClick_lnkBlockFriend Error",error)
        }
    );

    let updateRosterIq=$iq({ 'type': 'set', 'id': 'acceptedReq' })
        .c("query", {xmlns: Strophe.NS.ROSTER}).c("item", {jid: friendJid,ask:null, subscription: "remove"});
    connection.sendIQ(updateRosterIq,response=>{ console.log("onClick_lnkBlockFriend_rosterRemoval",response)},error=>{ console.log("onClick_lnkBlockFriend_rosterRemoval Error",error)});
}
```

**Code for unsubscribe handler**

```
function onPresence(presence) {
    console.log("presense obj",presence);
    var presence_type = $(presence).attr('type'); // unavailable, subscribed, etc...
    var from = $(presence).attr('from'); // presence coming from jabber_id
    var to = $(presence).attr('to'); // presence coming to jabber_id


    if(presence_type == 'unsubscribe')
    {
        connection.send($pres({ to: from, type: "unsubscribed" }));
        connection.send($pres({ to: from, type: "unavailable", }));        
    }

    return true;
}
```